# How to find the record size in berkley database?

Tags: berkeley-db

Is there any tool which can help in finding record size in berkley DB?

https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/related/berkeleydb.html

Answer (score 0):

`db_dump (1)` has them.  For example, on an RHEL/Centos Linux system, use `-da` to dump all debug information:

```
db_dump -da /var/lib/rpm/Name | head -100
...
    [000] 4088 len:   5 data: CUnit
    [001] 4076 len:   8 data: 8d05000000000000
    [002] 4060 len:  11 data: CUnit-devel
    [003] 4048 len:   8 data: 5006000000000000
    [004] 4040 len:   5 data: GeoIP
    [005] 4028 len:   8 data: 7105000000000000
    [006] 4008 len:  14 data: NetworkManager
    [007] 3996 len:   8 data: d705000000000000
```